# was bedeutet Ritter in der Brandung

Tags: idiom

Ich habe ein satzteil gesehen, als ich im internet ein Beitrag las. Nun ich wundere mich was bedeutet es eigentlich. Ist es eine deutsche Redewendung?

> Du verhälst dich in vielen Situationen nicht selbstbewusst und männlich genug, wodurch sie dich nicht mehr als ihren Helden bzw. **Ritter in der Brandung** sieht

Comment: "Fels in der Brandung" ist ein Idiom. Was der Ritter da soll, weiss ich nicht so rech. "Retter in der Brandung" wäre auch komisch.

Comment: Ich verstehe noch nicht, warum ein Fels(Rock) in der Brandung ist.

Comment: Weil das Wasser den Sand oder die Erde rundherum weggespült hat (Memmen, Weicheier), der Fels jedoch blieb standhaft.

Answer (score 3):

Ein **Fels in der Brandung** ist ein typisches Bild für eine Person, die sogar den Naturgewalten zu widerstehen vermag. Hinter so einem Felsen kann man sich vor allem Unbill der Welt verstecken, so eine Person ist ein ultimativer Beschützer. Normalerweise wird dieses Attribut Frauen angetragen.

Der *Ritter in der Brandung* ist hingegen ein falsches Mischbild aus dem *Ritter in glänzender Rüstung* und dem *Fels in der Brandung*. Ritter sollten besser nicht ins Meer gehen, und sich  am besten [auch von Klippen fernhalten.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8X1sjHBoRU)

Comment: Stimmt, aber "normalerweise wird dieses Attribut Frauen agetragen"? Wirklich? Und ja, die Rüstung würde wohl rosten. <g>

Comment: Von Männern wird es eher erwartet, dass sie den Naturgewalten trotzen. *Sie war sein Fels in der Brandung* scheint mir geläufiger als *Er war ihr Fels in der Brandung.*

Comment: Ich glaube, Janka hat sich nur verschrieben. Sie wird schon "wird dieses Attribut Männern zugesprochen" gemeint haben.

Comment: Neben "Ritter in glänzender Rüstung" sind als Bild für stabile, männliche Schutzgestalten auch einfach *Ritter* (ohne weitere Accessoires) oder auch *Märchenprinz* (oft ironisch) verbreitet. *Arme Ritter* sind dagegen eine bei Kindern beliebte Speise.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich glaube sie war gedanklich bei denen, die sich hinter so einem Felsen verstecken. Allerdings ist mir der Ritter in glänzender Rüstung nicht geläufig. Da drängt sich mir eher ein "Ritter in der Schlacht" auf, während glänzende Rüstung nach Burgspielen klingt, wo man keinen Schutz braucht.